# Programmatically provide NiFi InvokeHTTP different certificates

Tags: ssl-certificate, apache-httpclient-4.x, apache-nifi, nashorn

I have a requirement in Nifi where I have cycle through different HTTP**S** REST Endpoints and provide different certificates for some endpoints and different username / password for some other endpoints.

I used InvokeHTTP processor to send the requests, although URL takes an expression language, I cannot setup SSLContextService with an expression.

Alternatively, I thought on using ExecuteScript to call those Endpoints, however as [listed here in StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45568861/how-to-invoke-a-remote-rest-service-in-nifi/49565862); I still don't know how to programmatically call an external service through a script.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: you still can use two or more InvokeHTTP processors with different parameters and route between them using RouteOnAttribute. However it's possible to write script. Check groovy HttpBuilder for example.

Comment: There is an [existing Apache NiFi Jira (NIFI-1995)](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NIFI-1995) to allow for configurable alias selection given a keystore which contains multiple private keys.

Answer (score 3):

just for fun created the groovy script that calls http.

for sure you can avoid using it. and I believe `InvokeHTTP` processor covers almost all needs.

However.. going to call test rest service: `/post` at https://httpbin.org

the flow: `GenerateFlowFile` (generates body) -> `EcecuteGroovyScript` (call service)

The body generated by `GenerateFlowFile` : `{"id":123, "txt":"aaabbbccc"}`

In `ExecuteGroovyScript 1.5.0` declare the `CTL.ssl1` property and link it to `StandardSSLContextService`

[image: NiFi ExecuteGroovyScript configuration]

and now the script:

```groovy
@Grab(group='acme.groovy', module='acmehttp', version='20180301', transitive=false)
import groovyx.acme.net.AcmeHTTP
import org.apache.nifi.ssl.SSLContextService.ClientAuth

def ff=session.get()
if(!ff)return
def http
ff.write{ffIn, ffOut->
    http = AcmeHTTP.post(
        url:    "https://httpbin.org/post", //base url
        query: [aaa:"hello", bbb:"world!"], //query parameters
        // send flowfile content (stream) as a body
        body:   ffIn,
        headers:[
            //assign content-type from flowfile `mime.type` attribute
            "content-type":ff.'mime.type' 
        ],
        // you can declare `CTX.ssl1`, `CTX,.ssl2`,... processor properties and map them to SSLContextService
        // then depending on some condition create different SSLContext
        // in this case let's take `CTL.ssl1` service to create context
        ssl:  CTL["ssl"+1].createSSLContext(ClientAuth.WANT),
        // the next commented line creates trust all ssl context:
        //ssl:  AcmeHTTP.getNaiveSSLContext(), 

        // the receiver that transfers url response stream to flowfile stream
        receiver:{respStream, httpCtx-> ffOut << respStream }
    )
}
//set response hesders as flow file attributes with 'http.header.' prefix
http.response.headers.each{ k,v-> ff['http.header.'+k]=v }
//status code and message
ff.'http.status.code' = http.response.code
ff.'http.status.message' = http.response.message
if( http.response.code < 400){
    //transfer to success if response was ok
    REL_SUCCESS << ff
}else{
    //transfer to failure when response code is 400+
    REL_FAILURE << ff
}
```