# Groovy HTTPBuilder with custom sslContext

Tags: groovy, apache-nifi

I have a NiFi StandardSSLContextService that gives me a custom SSLContext.  Now I'm wondering, how to use this in an Groovy (via ExecuteScriptProcessor) httpconnection.  I have limited access to the machine, so I can't really install libraries, and have to use, what Nifi and Groovy provide (which should suffice, I hope).

I found no documentation on Groovy's HttpBuilder on http://groovy-lang.org (er...?).

all documentation I found elsewhere seemed pretty bulky (many posts from 2009, 20 lines or more for a simple https connect - I'd have thought, that this has become easier in the last 10 years, especially in groovy).

I'm not sure how to use the HTTPBuilder-ng, since it's documentation does not say, how to use a custom ssl context (not really, the part seems to have been editedt, and something went missing, or I'm mentally stuck in a hole; and I proably can't use it anyways, since I'd have to install it, right?).

So. What, how? This can't be difficult, if I have an sslcontext, I'd expect it to be a one-liner...

Thanks for any help on this!

Comment: Found something here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49578492/programmatically-provide-nifi-invokehttp-different-certificates for me, the @Grab will not work, since my server is not allowed to download stuff from the outside - but others might be able to use it.

Comment: HttpBuilder also is an external library to groovy / nifi. So, you have to download and put into `nifi/lib` the library you want to work with.

Comment: Sadly, I concur.  I added an existing jar-file in the modules (/myotherapp/bla/lib/httpclient-4.5.3.jar), then it worked.  could you put your statement as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the suggestion by @dagget already proved to be succesfull, I will place it here as an answer so that the question does not remain open:

> HttpBuilder also is an external library to groovy / nifi. So, you have
>   to download and put into nifi/lib the library you want to work with